# Does this imply that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(x+ \frac {1}{x}) }{f(x)}= 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that  $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$  is uniformly  continuous . Does this imply  that  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac {f(x+\frac{1}{x})}{f(x)}=1$$

My attempts: I think yes. Suppose I take $f(x)=\sin x$ , $f(x+ \frac{1}{x})= \sin(x+\frac{1}{x})$

As $\sin x$ is periodic.

Is  its  correct/not correct.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: An example is not a proof. You need to use the definition somewhere.

Comment: And (in most cases) one example shouldn't even be enough to form an idea of whether to try proving or disproving a statement.

Comment: Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin(x + 1/x)}{\sin x} = 1$?  How do you know?  Can your argument generalize?

Comment: @ Mattew  leingang.....my logic  $sinx$~$ x$    now   i  ussed   $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}( { x +  1/x}) =  lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} { x }+ lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{ 1/x} = lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} { x }$

Comment: As I think about it, I'm not sure this is true. I think that if $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ sufficiently quickly, this need not be the case. I'm having trouble coming up with an explicit counterexample though.

Comment: But $\sin x$ is only close to $x$ when $x$ is close to $0$, using that approximation when $x\to \infty$ is very wrong and bound to give wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not true. Consider the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ we know $f$ is positive and uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$ since it has a bounded derivative. However we also have:
$$\begin{align*}
 \frac{e^{-(x + 1/x)^2}}{e^{-x^2}} &= \frac{e^{-x^2}e^{-1/x^2}e^{-2}}{e^{-x^2}} \\
&=e^{-1/x^2}e^{-2} \\
& \rightarrow e^{-2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks joe.........

Answer (score 1):

Check "the limit" of your expression for eg. the function $f(x) := \frac1{x+1} \left[ sin\left(\frac\pi2 x^2 \right) +2 \right]$ through integer values of $x$, even and odd separately. You get two different values so the limit does not exist.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and you can easily continuously extend $f(x)$ at $x=0$, it is uniformly continuous.

This shows that the limit does not have to exist, but even if it exists, it might differ from 1 (example by Joe).